# Align text of gridview items

Tags: xaml, winui-3

I want to align the text of the GridView items to center.
How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```cs
namespace Notenmanager
{
    public class YearPageInitializer
    {
        public static void initialyze(Page page, string year)
        {
            GridView gridView = new ();
    
            ObservableCollection<string> grades = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            grades.Add("Deutsch \n\n6");
            gridView.ItemsSource = grades;
    
            gridView.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            gridView.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
    
            var grid = page.FindName("g") as Grid;
            grid.Children.Add(gridView);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a single `string`, I would create a `record` or a `class`:

```cs
public record Grade(string Subject, int Value);
```

then create an `ItemTemplate` with individual `TextBlock`s so we can align the texts:

```cs
GridView gridView = new();

ObservableCollection<Grade> grades = new();
grades.Add(new Grade("Deutsch", 6));
gridView.ItemsSource = grades;

gridView.ItemTemplate = XamlReader.Load(
    """
    <DataTemplate xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding Subject}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding Value}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    """) as DataTemplate;

var grid = page.FindName("g") as Grid;
grid.Children.Add(gridView);
```